# It's there a way to get /system partition permanent read/write access even after reboot?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, adb, file-system, partitions, system

I used ADB.exe to get access to my System partition, I linked the dalvik-cache folder there to save space on my data partition, but the problem is I need to convert it read/write everytime I want to install a new app (or even if the old app wants to update), is there a way to make the partition always read/write instead read-only? Thanks!

Comment: I reckon that needs to be done on a kernel level...

Comment: That means I need a custom kernel, right? My device doesn't have development of a custom kernel... thanks for your answer!

Comment: Not even most custom kernels would do it (not really useful unless under certain situations like yours). I think you could look up `init.d` and have a `init.d` script that do the remount job on reboot for you. Can't really guarantee it will work though - I've seldom had luck executing `init.d` scripts that requires `su`.

Comment: @AndyYan A custom kernel with `init.d` support is **unnecessary**. I'll post an answer soon.

Comment: Yeah I didn't say a custom kernel is necessary, but I was thinking `init.d` is. The 3rd one you raise is an interesting one I've never seen though.

Comment: I want to add also, that auto RW mount is a **huge** security flaw.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to make `/system` permanently R/W. You just need to mount it as R/W at every boot. So I'm providing you with a few options to mount `/system` as R/W at boot automatically, but do note that these methods mount `/system` as R/W in **master mount namespace**, which means *ALL* programs can write to it as long as file permission is right. This creates a *severely huge* security flaw. Do it at your own risk.
The following options are not *steps of a single method*, but *different approaches*.

1. If you can modify your boot image, then editing `/init.rc` is the best and easiest way.
2. If you can't modify `/boot` directly, but `init.d` is availble, you can write a simple script to mount `/system` as R/W. As is mentioned in comments, it may not go right through if you try to call `su` from an `init.d` script.
3. If both 1 and 2 is unavailable and you have root <sub>(I suppose you do by asking this question)</sub>, replace a system service (`debuggerd` is the best choice) binary with a custom shell script. Then run `start debuggerd` to activate it (effective from next boot).

The script required by method 2 and 3 is very simple, like below.

```
#!/system/bin/sh
/system/bin/mount -o rw,remount /system
```

You probably would like to add a sleep loop after it if you use method 3, as whenever `debuggerd` exits, it will be restarted.

BTW, you can easily add `init.d` support by yourself with method 3. Just take a glance at [this](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2326161). However in my opinion, re-partitioning is the best way to utilize free space `/system`, yet it's potentially harmful.

Comment: Method 3 seems conceived by a malware writer. I like it. +1.